# ATL macros only working on devel-computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, atl

i use ATL macros like A2T and A2CW.
on the devel-computer everyhting works fine. when i use the application (visual studio 2008 pro) on another computer - the output of the ATL-macro-conversion is not readable.

i hope someone can help me to solve this problem. my application is finished - only the ATL conversion macros are the problem atm.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The A2X macros use the current codepage to convert the strings. If you have literal strings (or some data you are distributing with the application) that you are converting, that were created with the codepage of the dev. computer in mind, and the other computer has a different codepage set, they will end up as gibberish. You can use APIs to explicitly specify the codepage you're converting from if this is the case. A2X macros should really only be used for content than comes as input from the user, where the codepage may vary, not for data where the codepage is known ahead of time.